# android 4.0.3 ScrollingTabContainerView NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Our Android Application randomly crashes (very hard to repro the issue) with the following stack trace . This is seen when the orientation of the device is changed from portrait to landscape from the logcat logs. Also this issue has been seen on devices with Android 4.0.3 version. So wanted to check if it is a known issue with 4.0.3? Not sure from the code how to debug this issue as the stack trace is entirely of Android platform with no involvement of App code.

```
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView.onItemSelected(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:352)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:882)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:865)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.widget.AdapterView.checkSelectionChanged(AdapterView.java:1017)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.widget.AdapterView.handleDataChanged(AdapterView.java:999)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:179)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:285)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(HorizontalScrollView.java:1159)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onMeasure(HorizontalScrollView.java:303)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView.onMeasure(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:117)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.onMeasure(ActionBarView.java:878)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.onMeasure(ActionBarContainer.java:173)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-21 17:44:01.761 E/UncaughtException( 3344):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: These information is not enough, unfortunately this log don't tell us when crashes the application, when this problem happened again try to obtain the next file "/data/anr/traces.txt", this file save other logs of app's crashes.
Maybe will be necessary to see a bit of code and learn more about what makes the application.

Comment: Thank you. ANR traces.txt only has logs from months ago, what might have been true till yesterday since I hardly use this specific tablet, but today and yesterday I had lots of crashes that are not in there. I only encounter the crash on Android 4.0.3, other versions are fine. It happends on orientation change. Problem is I cannot see where (or if) it is initiated from my own code.

Comment: I noticed this as a missing class when I was removing ActionBarSherlock and switching to the Android Actionbar (not ActionBarCompat). I was editing my app to have on ICS+ support. Did you switch from ActionBarSherlock?

Comment: No, I did not switch from ActionBarSherlock. Problem is back when I switch back to android:windowActionBarOverlay=false. My crashlogs also show it for a 4.0.4 device.

Answer (score -1):

I really have no clue where this error is coming from. I fixed it by changing

```
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
```

into

```
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

in my main style for Android v15. It makes my app a little less beautiful for this Android version, but that is alright. I hope it's only a 4.0.3 bug, I have 6 tablets with other Android versions that are doing fine.

Comment: This does **not** fix the issue. I implemented this and still see these NPEs on API level 15.